# How can I refinish an interior chimney pipe to make it appear rounded?

Tags: drywall, plaster, chimney, lath-and-plaster

Right now my interior chimney pipe is hidden behind a wall and I want to remove that wall and expose the pipe, but the pipe itself is not so pretty.

My fireplace is a wood fireplace with a double isolated chimney pipe of about 10 inchs in diameter.

I'm looking to do something like this :

[image]

[image]

Those pictures comes from my neighbor's house. He said to me that it was done with plaster.

This is exactly my fireplace, but the chimney pipe is behind a wall right now.
How can I achieve this rounded chimney pipe ?

Comment: Ask your neighbor for the number to the guy who did his.

Comment: Unfortunately, he's the third owner of the house and the chimney was already like this when he bought the house.

Comment: What is the diameter of your interior chimney pipe and what is the finished diameter f your neighbours interior chimney pipe? From that we _might_ be able to deduce how your neighbours was done...

Comment: Hi, sory for the delay.
The pipe is about 10inch of diameter.

But I don't know for the outter diameter of my neighbour finished pipe. I would say maybe 20inch in diameter.

Comment: Can you replace the pipe with a steel one? http://www.chimney-liner-central.com/rigid_chimney_liner.html

Comment: No, it would be to much work as the pipe is about 2 stories high and embeded in walls.

Answer (score 2):

Where I live, there are two or three places that specialize in fireplaces, like a re-modeler's dream.  Find what you have locally and take a picture of your fireplace and your neighbors fireplace (before and after) and explain what it takes to change yours.  Then you will know what you need and whether it is something you want to handle as a DIY'er or pay to have done.  When you learn more you can search the whole world wide web. (I love saying that) to even help you take it to the next level.